# Crosschecking account number between two access tables when using forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am using a form to enter new data into the table: `tblMonthlySummary`. I am entering Account Number, Currency, and Closing Local Balance.

When I enter the account number into table `tblMonthlySummary`, I would like Access, either through a macro or VBA, to crosscheck the table `tblStaticBankDetails` for the account number that would be added to `tblMonthlySummary`.

If the account number does not exist in `tblStaticBankDetails`, I would like VBA or a macro to return a Windows dialog box that says, "`Invalid account number`".

Here is the current code I have in VBA for my Add Entry to Table Button, Clear Fields, and Close Form. These buttons are on a form labeled: `frmMonthlyManualUpdate`.

### Add Data Code

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMonthlySummary([Account Number], [Currency], [Closing Balance]) " & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.txtAccountNumber & "','" & Me.cboGender2 & "', '" & Me.txtClosingBalance & "')"

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form
    frmMonthlySummarySub.Form.Requery

    'confirmation of end
    MsgBox "Account number and balance successfully recorded."
End Sub
```

`Me.cbogender2` is my currency blank.

### Clear Fields Code

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtAccountNumber = ""
    Me.cboGender2 = ""
    Me.txtClosingBalance = ""

    'focus on TxtAccountNumber
    Me.txtAccountNumber.SetFocus
End Sub
```

### Close Form Code

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just use a combo box for the account number, so the user can choose from only valid account number values?

Comment: The table monthly summary is populated by a downloadable excel file that is appended monthly automatically. The date being entered in this form is account numbers that are not currently in the summary. Also there are over 1000 accounts so it would take a long time to scroll through.

Comment: As the user types a number into the combo box, Access automagically highlights the first matching combo row.  That should not consume more of the user's time than typing the same number into a text box.  I don't think we are on the same page here, and that's likely my fault ... but I still don't understand why.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, I should create a combo box for the account number entry on the form. I should link that combo box to the account numbers in my "tblStaticBankDetails" and then it will populate to as the use types in numbers? I am new to access so I don't now some of the features yet.

Also with this solution I would still like to know the code for crosschecking columns across tables for future reference in case you know that.

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query as the combo's RowSource, ie `SELECT [Account Number] FROM tblStaticBankDetails ORDER BY 1;`  When the user types in the digit `2`, the first combo row starting with `2` is selected.  When the user adds a `3` after the `2`, the first row starting with `23` is selected.  Sounds to me like you just need to try it and see it in action.  :-)

Comment: I just tried out the combo box and it is great! The only thing I would like to be able to do is to edit the error message when a non-existent account number is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combo box is the way to go.

You can set it's properties to only allow values that are on it's list to be entered into the field.    Users can either choose a value from it's list OR type the account manually.  It won't let a value be entered that is not on the list.

How many accounts might have their summary row missing?

If it's only a small number you might want to consider:

1. Using SQL to insert the account numbers that are not in tblMonthlySummary that are in tblStaticBankDetails.
2. Then the user can see which ones are missing and find out what the values should be.  (ie filter to form to view account with missing details)
3. It is strange that you are using a button to execute and insert statement.   It is more common for an Access form to be based on an updatable record source (like you list) and for the user to simply click the "new record" button to insert a row.

PS.  I would expect referential integrity to be set up between these two tables to stop any incorrect values being entered for account number as well.

Harvey

Comment: The summary row is missing about 20 bank accounts. 

Could you possible explain in greater detail how to use SQL to insert account numbers and do that cross checking process?

Also I for your number 3 I avoided that because I did not want to have to explain to the end user to click the new record button. I simply wanted them to be able to enter information in an easy to use box.

As for referential integrity I am not sure what that is or how it works? Could you explain further?

Finally is there a way to edit the error message from a combo box when a non-existent account number is entered?

Comment: Sorry you ask me to explain to much. this youtube has videos that will epxlain more than I can here.   https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYMOUCVo86jEeMMdaaq03jQ_t9nFV737s   When you set up a combo box it will not let you enter a value that isn't on the list - try it!   You need to think about what happens if the same acocunt number gets entered twice - ie used primary key indexes!